# Are Android Bluetooth file transfers encrypted?

Tags: encryption, android, bluetooth

Suppose I pair two Android phones together using Bluetooth and transfer a file from the first phone to the second by sharing the file using Bluetooth. Does Android encrypt the file transfer so that no third party can intercept the Bluetooth transfer and obtain the contents of the file? If the transfer is encrypted, what kind of encryption does Android use?

Comment: Bluetooth encrypts the connection, not Android.